# Scripts are not loading after the page transition in Barba.jS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, barbajs

So I have one index file that has few js files are included like Gsap & Barba JS. But I have one inner page that includes some extra js files such as locomotive.js & OWLcarousel.js and please note that these two Js files (locomotive.js & OWLcarousel.js) are not included on index page as they are not required. The issue is the inner page opens after completing the index page transition but without loading these two JS files (locomotive.js & OWLcarousel.js). As a result both locomotive scrolling & OWL carousel are not working. However, If I'll refresh the inner page once then these two Js files (locomotive.js & OWLcarousel.js) are loading and everything works fine. So how to load JS files in Barba.Js for inner pages?

Update:
I have created a minimal demo and you can see that inner page is not loading the JS and CSS of Locomotive and also OWL carousel if click on heading text on homepage and navigate to inner. But if refresh the page then both locomotive & owl carousel are working fine in inner page. How to fix this? I have added the suggested change to the JS file (https://bootstrap-awesome.com/barba-test1f/js/main-test.js) Demo Link: https://bootstrap-awesome.com/barba-test1f/index-test.html

So I tried to load the additional JS files in the same below format but nothing happens. Can anyone guide me with this please?

```
barba.init({
  views: [{
        namespace: 'home',
        beforeEnter({ next }) {

        // load your script
        let script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = '<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/locomotive-scroll@3.5.4/dist/locomotive-scroll.min.js"></script>'; 
script.src = '<script src="js/owl/owl.carousel.js"></script>';
        next.container.appendChild(script);
        }, 
    }],
```

[image]

[image: Error in the Network console]

**UPDATE**
@wouch

The below is what I have tried but still not working. Also, how to load Locomotive external CSS?

JS: bootstrap-awesome.com/barba-test1f/js/main-test.js

Demo : https://bootstrap-awesome.com/barba-test1f/index-test.html

```
views: [{
    namespace: 'home',
    beforeEnter({ next }) {
      // Script URLs to load
      let pageScriptSrcs = [
        'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/locomotive-scroll@3.5.4/dist/locomotive-scroll.min.js',
        'js/custom-scroll.js',
        'js/owl/owl.carousel.js',
        'js/owl/owl-custom.js'
      ]
      
      pageScriptSrcs.forEach(scriptSrc => {
        let script = '<script src="' + scriptSrc + '"><\/script>';
        console.log(script);
        next.container.appendChild(script);
      })
    }
    },
    {
    namespace: 'projdetailpage',
    beforeEnter({ next }) {
      // Script URLs to load
      let pageScriptSrcs = [
        'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/locomotive-scroll@3.5.4/dist/locomotive-scroll.min.js',
        'js/custom-scroll.js',
        'js/owl/owl.carousel.js',
        'js/owl/owl-custom.js'
      ]
      
      pageScriptSrcs.forEach(scriptSrc => {
        let script = '<script src="' + scriptSrc + '"><\/script>';
        console.log(script);
        next.container.appendChild(script);
      })
    }

  }],
```

Comment: It could be something with the paths. Have you checked in the Network-tab in your developer tools, if the files are attempted to be loaded but gives a 404? ... And can you add to your question, how these two files are loaded/added to your project. It might be something related to that.

Comment: @zeth added the error screenshots from the network console. Can you please have a look? But everything works fine if I refresh the page but not after the page transition from home to inner page.

Comment: It looks like you're creating a `<script>` element on line 341, and then setting the script source of that element as everything in both the `locomotive.js` & `OWLcarousel.js` embeds. Have you tried just appending each of those scripts to the `next.container` instead?

Comment: @wouch Can you pls show me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this, where you add the scripts you want in an array, then loop through each one and build a `<script src="..."></script>` string and append to the `next` container.

```js
barba.init({
  views: [{
    namespace: 'home',
    beforeEnter({ next }) {
      // Script URLs to load
      let pageScriptSrcs = [
        'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/locomotive-scroll@3.5.4/dist/locomotive-scroll.min.js',
        'js/owl/owl.carousel.js'
      ]
      
      pageScriptSrcs.forEach(scriptSrc => {
        let script = '<script src="' + scriptSrc + '"><\/script>';
        console.log(script);
        next.container.appendChild(script);
      })
    },
  }],
})
```

Comment: I have created a minimal demo and you can see that inner page is not loading the  JS and CSS of Locomotive and also OWL carousel if click on heading text on homepage and navigate to inner. But if refresh the page then both locomotive & owl carousel  are working fine in inner page. How to fix this? I have added the suggested change to the JS file (https://bootstrap-awesome.com/barba-test1f/js/main-test.js) 
Demo Link:  https://bootstrap-awesome.com/barba-test1f/index-test.html

Comment: Because of the `views` where the `beforeEnter ({})` is contained only refers to the `'home'` namespace this script will only run on that page. You would want to add the JS to every namespace you want it to run in, or use [barba.js hooks](https://barba.js.org/docs/advanced/hooks/)

Comment: wouch - so you mean to say that a separate name space for inner page like below in this case, right? So locomotive CSS also add there?
views: [{
    namespace: 'projdetailpage',
    beforeEnter({ next }) {
      let pageScriptSrcs = [
        'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/locomotive-scroll@3.5.4/dist/locomotive-scroll.min.js',
        'js/owl/owl.carousel.js'
      ]
      
      pageScriptSrcs.forEach(scriptSrc => {
        let script = '<script src="' + scriptSrc + '"><\/script>';
        console.log(script);
        next.container.appendChild(script);
      })
    },
  }],

Comment: Hi Wouch, I have updated the js file (https://bootstrap-awesome.com/barba-test1f/js/main-test.js) but still the scripts are not loading. Can you tell me what mistake i am making here, please? Also, how to load locomotive CSS here?